# should i be using var in node js or does it use es6 convention

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

im new to node and ive been using let and const mostly for declaring variables, but in searching through documentation im reading a lot of references to using var as a variable instead of let, does nodejs use the same variable scoping as vanilla js and the reference documents im reading just outdated?

Comment: Node is using vanilla JS. It's just an environment that executes your code, not a different version of JavaScript.

Comment: Node.js is normally supporting all the latest versions of JS and it is actually using the V8 engine to execute JS. so you can use 'let' too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both Node and browser run JavaScript in the same fashion, they both adhere to EcmaScript, which specifies the rules of JavaScript.

There are ways to [know exactly](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) which ES6 features are supported, but NodeJS has been supporting `let` and `const` since a long time. The only disparity you should probably worry about is ESM vs CommonJS but it doesn't have anything to do with var/let/const.

So I'd encourage you to use `let` and `const` instead of `var` when writing NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either, Node.js supports both let and const since version 6.0.0, see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let.

I would recommend using block scoped statements: `let` and `const`, since this is more consistent with other languages.